# Input field cannot type other characters

Tags: javascript, html

May I know what error cause my input field cannot type characters? Because after set `></\":*?|` these symbol restrict in the input field, other character cannot type in the input field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Can't type character in the input field</h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control blank" id="function_code" name="function_code" title="function_code" onpaste="return false">
<div id="error-box"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function showError (key) {
  var errBox = document.querySelector("#error-box");
  errBox.textContent = "The character " + key.toString() + " is not allowed!";
  //Dismiss the error
  window.setTimeout(function () {
      errBox.textContent = "";
  }, 10000)
}


document.getElementById("function_code").onkeypress = function(e) {
var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

if ("></\":*?|".indexOf(chr) >= 0)
  showError(chr)
  return false;
};
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your "keypress" handler always returns `false`, so no key will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ("></\":*?|".indexOf(chr) >= 0){
  showError(chr)
   return false;
}
return true // !!!
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Can't type character in the input field</h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control blank" id="function_code" name="function_code" title="function_code" onpaste="return false">
<div id="error-box"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function showError (key) {
  var errBox = document.querySelector("#error-box");
  errBox.textContent = "The character " + key.toString() + " is not allowed!";
  //Dismiss the error
  window.setTimeout(function () {
      errBox.textContent = "";
  }, 10000)
}


document.getElementById("function_code").onkeypress = function(e) {
var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

if ("></\":*?|".indexOf(chr) >= 0){
  showError(chr)
   return false;
}
return true
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the return false;
or change it to true

if you return false nothing will be typed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Can't type character in the input field</h1>


<input type="text" class="form-control blank" id="function_code" name="function_code" title="function_code" onpaste="return false">
<div id="error-box"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function showError (key) {
  var errBox = document.querySelector("#error-box");
  errBox.textContent = "The character " + key.toString() + " is not allowed!";
  //Dismiss the error
  window.setTimeout(function () {
      errBox.textContent = "";
  }, 10000)
}


document.getElementById("function_code").onkeypress = function(e) {
var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

if ("></\":*?|".indexOf(chr) >= 0)
  showError(chr)
};
</script>
```